# Back button after redirecting to external page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web

I am working on a Ruby on Rails toy project. I have two main pages A and B. A has a form that takes input and does a post request. The result is being displayed at page B. Then there is the option to redirect to an external page (let's call it E) from B.

The problem is that if I click the back button from E, it doesn't go back to B but it fails as it doesn't find any parameters (form's text input from A).

Is this a common issue? How can I solve it?

Edit: Another version of this problem is going to B from A using post, then using the click button to go back to A and finally using the next button to go to B. It will fail as we're going to B without any parameters.

Comment: Are you rendering B after the post or do you redirect to B?

Comment: Yes, after the post B is being displayed and provides an internal link (base_url/:param) that redirects to E based on a DB mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Posting and then rendering is generally not recommended. That is probably the cause of the issue with clicking the back button on E. The back button is trying to resubmit the form instead of displaying B. I would try to redirect to B after submitting the form on A.